# configuring codeigniter smtp on godaddy shared server

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I have tried the code below and keep getting this error

> Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

```
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'mail.keytimeng.com'; //change this
$config['smtp_port'] = '25';
$config['smtp_user'] = 'info@keytimeng.com'; //change this
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'xxxx'; //change this
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$config['newline'] = "\r\n"; 
$this->email->initialize($config);
```

Comment: i also tried : $config['smtp_host'] = 'relay-hosting.secureserver.net';

Comment: ask go daddy support